# Web Translations Based on Country

Tags: .net, localization, internationalization, translation, angular-translate

Since forever, my CMSs have asked for a Language Code in order for consumers to place different translations per text Key.  Also, the CMS takes Country into account for the sake of altering product availability, Currency, Date formats, etc.  **Edit v. Mike** But the website text is always based on a Language Selection chosen by the visitor, and has little or nothing to do with their country.

For some reason, a client has asked that their CMS be updated so they can provide translations for all combinations of Language/Country including:

- English - Germany
- English - Nigeria
- etc.

As far as I can tell, Angular Translate only takes a Language Code into account, not a Country Code or Culture-Code.

So how common is it that Web Translations take Country/Language into account instead of just Language?  And what frameworks handle that?  I specifically use C#.NET and AngularJS Translations

Comment: It is not very common, and it is extremely annoying that it is not more common.  I live in The Netherlands, and I am sick and tired of web sites displaying themselves to me in Dutch even though Dutch is not one of the languages I have configured on my browser.  Country of residence has nothing to do with language spoken.  Please fulfil your client's request.

Comment: @MikeNakis My CMS's allow you to choose a Country and Language.  And Dutch is one of those languages, but Frisian is not.  So of course it would default to Dutch, but allow you to change it to English, French, Japanese, and more.  The answer to your frustration would be to request that Frisian be added (Or whatever language you speak).  Not to change the CMS to allow administrators to enter some combination of Country/Language.  But IF Frisian was added, Frisian would become the default language if Netherlands was chosen.

Comment: Frisian? Good guess, but no, I just want English. And when I click on the flag icon of a website to change my language, the web site usually shows me a list of countries, not languages.  That's what is extremely annoying.  So if I select UK in order to see English, I am taken to their English web site, which only shows their English products etc.  I want their Dutch products shown to me in English, but very few web sites offer such flexibility.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is definitely annoying.  In my case I am not asking about that.  Whatever site you're talking about should be more sensitive to that.  My sites running my CMS ask for Language separate from Country.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is somewhat a template which describes my understanding of my answer, but also allows other answers to key off of what I'm looking for, and argue against some of my points.

I am American and I speak English.  So my experience is limited (in many ways).  But I believe this:

Internationalization means my website can differ based on a Visitor's Location.  It can differ in many ways, such as:

- The text language
- The text grammar/spelling (dialect?)
- Imagery on the site
- Date Time Formatting
- Currency and Symbology
- More..

In this case, I am ONLY Talking about Text.  So basically just Translations.

I note that I DO take Location into account for all other things.  And that I do take Language Selection into account so users can select their language.  But I currently do NOT allow them to select something like:

- en-DE
- en-NG
- jp-DE

That is because Japanese in Japan and Japanese in Germany are the same thing, as far as I know.  And English in Nigeria and Germany are the same as English in the USA and Europe...

**EXCEPT** I realize that some spelling `color / colour` and some grammar are slightly different.  But how much different?  Enough to change from the scheme of hiring ONE Translator per language to MANY Different Translators for special dialects based on region?

As far as I can tell, it isn't common in web development to break down to those minute differences.  And while using a framework such as AngularJS Translate, it only asks for the Language Key to be passed around (AJAX'd in my case).  Granted, I could easily make that language key say "FartFace-McButterEater" if I wanted to, but that isn't the intended use.

So while other answers might include other frameworks and examples.  I'd say that those are off-cases and rare in the scope of the web.